# API returning company tickers found in provided news article

Tags: programming, finance, data

I'm looking for a REST API (paid or free) that accepts a string containing a news article (example below) as payload and returns an array of company tickers (eg TSLA for Tesla) mentioned in the article.

#### Example Article Snippet

> COMPETITIVE INSIGHTS
>
> Few of the noted market players in the global SDN orchestration market are Iphotonix, LLC, Nokia Corporation, Netcracker Technology,
>   Cenx, Inc., Ciena Corporation, Qualisystems Ltd., Juniper Networks,
>   Huawei Technologies Co. Ltd., Virtela Technology (acquired by NTT
>   Communications), Glueware, Inc., Cisco Systems, Inc., Ubiqube PLC,
>   Hewlett Packard Enterprise (HP), ZYMR Systems Pvt. Ltd., and Anuta
>   Networks.

#### Expected JSON Response

```
{
  "tickers": [
    "SHE: 002502",
    "HPQ",
    "JNPR"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for paid or free service?

Comment: Paid or free - whatever does the job best